# Access API on server on Laravel, Web work but when access with API get error 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-8

My Directory
public_html/mobile/ <-- Laravel install File, which fokus on API.

There are other code in the public_html, which currently I did to make for the Web.

On Localhost:
When test with Localhost everything work fine with .htaccess, but if I delete .htaccess, the API fail to work.

On Server:
If got .htacess in public_html/mobile/public the Laravel fail to run
I delete the .htaccess in public_html/mobile/public, it manage to run the Laravel welcome pages. When I try to call the API I get "error 404"

Comment: My main focus is to call, The API

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear.
But I think this will solve your problmen:

You do not want to put the laravel folder inside of the public_html. This is a major security issue.

You have to put the laravel folder outside of the public_html folder.

In the public html folder you make a new folder, for example app. In this app folder you copy all the files from the laravel/public folder.

Now you only have to edit the index.php in your public_html/app folder and change the paths inside there to the correct path of your laravel installation.

```
line 34: require __DIR__.'/../../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
line 47: $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

More documentation on how to install laravel on shared hosting ([link](https://www.iankumu.com/blog/deploy-laravel-on-shared-hosting/))

Comment: Instead of copying files from laravel/public to public_html, OP can simply create [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link?useskin=vector) to laravel/public

Comment: @AdrianKokot True, the problem with that approach is that you need ssh access. Some shared hosting providers do not allow ssh access.

Comment: For now, I want to set it, in the development server First, afterward I will make it Live.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizAbdullah you will still need to follow this approach, it does not matter if it is live or development. You are still working on a server, not your local machine.

Comment: Okay will do this.  I will try to set it